# Align downscaled graphics to the left

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, width, adjustbox

I include a PDF as a figure in my document, and the PDF is a great deal wider than the `\linewidth`. I use the `adjustbox` package to set the width to slightly more than \linewidth, but I can't figure out how to make it flow over the left margin rather than the right.

```
% in the preamble
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

% in the document body 
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth+2cm]{figure.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

If I replace the `width` option with `left` or `inner`, then the figure is stretched to it's original size and then some, and if I add these options after `width` then they seem to be ignored.

Following suggestions from other answers here, I tried wrapping the graphics in a box like the following, but to no avail:

```
\makebox[\textwidth+2cm][l]{
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth+2cm]{figure.pdf}
}
```

How can I let the graphics respect the right margin and flow over the left margin instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want it like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} %% just for demo
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth+2cm\relax,right]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another show:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe} %% just for demo
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth+2cm\relax,outer]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth+2cm\relax,outer]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is *exactly* what I want! Thank you so much!